# How to unit test a method that is dependent on another?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux

I have a React and Redux project I'm trying to unit test with Chai testing framework.  Right now I'm writing a test for a reducer I have, and several of actions this reducer handles call helper methods.  Here is an example:

**formsReducer.js:**

```
import * as types from '../constants/actionTypes';
import objectAssign from 'object-assign';
import initialState from './initialState';
import formsHelper from '../utils/FormsHelper';
export default function formsReducer(state = initialState.forms, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.UPDATE_PRODUCT: {
        let formBlueprints = formsHelper.getFormsByProductId(action.product.id);
        formBlueprints = formsHelper.addOrRemoveMnDisclosure(formBlueprints, action.stateOfResidence.id);
        return objectAssign({}, state, {blueprints: formBlueprints, instances: []});
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, if I test this method I'm dependent on the `formsHelper.getFormsByProductId` and `formsHelper.addOrRemoveMnDisclosure` methods to pass as well.  How should I test this reducer/action?  Should I make a separate set of test data that can be returned from these methods when a certain product.id is passed to these methods?

Comment: Can't you just mock them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options here: You could intercept the request with [`nock`](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) (if it makes an http call) or mock the dependency with [`proxyquire`](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire). Assuming you are using `mocha` in conjunction with `chai`, here are some examples to get you started.

#### `nock` example

```
const nock = require('nock');

describe('your test', () => {
  if('should do things', () => {
    nock('http://your-domain')
      .get('/forms/1') // <---- or any other resource
      .reply(200, { /* your response object for testing */ });

    /* Your regular test */
  });
});
```

#### `proxyquire` example

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');

describe('your test', () => {
  if('should do things', () => {
    const formsReducer = proxyquire.noCallThru().load('../reducers/forms', {
      formsHelper: {
        /* any keys you need mocked/replaced for your test */
        getFormsByProductId: id => return { /* mock response */ }
      }
    });

    /* Your regular test */
  });
});
```

Comment: How does proxyquire compare to `sinon.js`?  Do they provide the same mocking functionality?  I'm new to using mocks, stubs, etc in unit testing and trying to learn all these different tools.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with `sinon.js`. Not sure if it supports replacing calling code like this, I thought it only provides spies to capture calls. I'm probably wrong in that assumption though.